# Linking FactoryBot associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Consider the following factories:

```
factory :position do
  association :underlying
end

factory :short_put, class: 'Trade' do
  position { association :position }
  strike { 115 }
end
```

I want to run tests against the Position instance associated with the short_put instance of Trade. If I instantiate the following variables:

```
@position = create(:position)
@short_put = create(:short_put)
```

Then two separate Positions are initiated and saved to the database. Only the `@short_put` is associated with a Position.

To test the Position associated with :short_put, I use `@short_put.position`. This works but I feel there must be a better way. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted this:

```
factory :position do
  association :underlying

  trait :with_short_put do
    after :build do |position|
      position.short_puts << build(:short_put, position: position)
      #position.short_put = build(:short_put, position: position) #when has one
    end
  end
end
```

after use

```
create(:position, :with_short_put)
```